# How to hide top Activity and let previous Activity respond to touch events

Tags: android, android-activity, background, touch

I have an `AsyncTask` which calls an `Activity (A)` which constantly checks whether Wifi has been turned on. Underneath it there is another `Activity (B)` which I'd like the user to still be able to carry on with. A is invisible on top of B and because of this, touch events are not being registered on B.

Is there a way for A to not have a `View` at all but can still have `Activity` characteristics and can carry on with what it's doing in the background, meanwhile B is accepting touch events?

Comment: Why you need Activity Characteristics in A Activity ?

Comment: Because I need it to keep checking whether Wifi is available and that can only be done by accessing ConnectivityManager which is a system service?

Comment: I would recommend using a Service in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try like this.let your activity implement Runnable..
create a thread in oncreate

```
public class youractivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
......
boolean bool=true; 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.....
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
Thread t=new Thread();
t.start();
.....
}

public void run()
{
 while (true){
  if (connectivityManager != null) {
    networkInfo =
        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
   if(networkInfo!=bool){

   bool=networkInfo;
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(youractivity.this,
                "wifi: "+String.valueOf(networkInfo),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              });
   }
}

 }
}
```

Comment: I've already done the thread to check wifi, which works, I just want it to run in the background.

Comment: i couldn't get you... but this thread runs in background.. :S

Comment: see my edited answer.. in this .. your activity starts a thread.... which checks for wifi in background only..... and your activity is visible for users also...

Comment: there is only 1 activity here... that is activity B as in your example... which is checking for  wifi by creating a thread t.... so this checking process is not visisble to users... just you will get the updates by toast... if you dont need the updates also.. you can remove the toast..

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused the English word meaning *Activity*, and the *Activity* in the context of Android.

> If I'm mistaken please enlighten me , What are the *Activity characteristics* that you want for Activity (A).

If I'm not mistaken, here , you need only **one** Activity . ***Activity (B)*** . To achieve your task of *constantly checking whether Wifi has been turned on* you can start a new thread from the *Activity (B)*.

---

Another option accomplishing the task of *constantly checking whether Wifi has been turned on* is a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).